# JTable Calendar Model

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am trying to learn to make calendar by this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/TheCalendarprogram.htm). But, I have problem in this line:

```
CalendarModel model = new CalendarModel();
```

It says that `CalendarModel` does not exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be something else.The [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/TheCalendarprogram.htm) you provided works fine.I'd suggest you to cross-check the code once again.